# браузерная игра на php ее интерфейс

Tags: php, разработка-игр

делаем игру на php (браузерную), нужно сделать ее с интерфейсом. на чем лучше его написать и как связать кроме HTML ??

Comment: http://phaser.io и  для сервера лучше nodejs, но никак не php )

Comment: У Вас не так много вариантов: HTML, HTML5 Canvas или плагины (Flash, Java, Silverlight). Лучше HTML или HTML5 Canvas, так как нативно. В остальном, все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: я думаю вы сильно себе облегчите работу, если будете использовать игровой движок, а платформа в данном случае уже последнее дело, поскольку современные движки поддерживают массу платформ [_Рейтинг игровых движков_](https://habrahabr.ru/post/307952/) я бы рекомендовал начать копать в сторону [_unity_](https://unity3d.com/ru/unity)